# Accessing/Recording Audio Output of a Teams Meeting using Bot Framework and GraphAPI

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-graph-teams, azure-bot-service

**How can I record audio from a Microsoft Teams meeting using a bot built with Graph API and Bot Framework?**

**Context** I have a Node.js web application that uses Microsoft's Graph API and Bot Framework on Azure to create a bot that can join Microsoft Teams meetings. The bot is currently able to join meetings without any issues, but I am struggling to find a way to record the audio of these meetings. I will need the recordings to be initiated automatically once the bot as joined the meeting successfully.

**What I've tried** I have looked into the Graph API documentation and found that it provides access to real-time audio and video streams, but It seems to only be compatible with .NET. I have also seen that it's possible to fetch transcripts and recordings of a Teams meeting using the Graph API, but I am not sure if the bot can start the Teams recording itself. Any suggestions? Thanks !